# I need to update a document field in my Database

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Can anyone help me?

- Error on my terminal is *ReferenceError: cart is not defined* for "cart.isPaid = true"
- Am I using the correct syntax to pass
  a parameter in Cart.findById(data.orders.cartId)?

I am trying to update a document field in my database "isPaid" to true.

Here's the payload I am using in Postman.

"orders": [
{
"productId": "6287b0884d17cb0dde9ecc57",
"cartId": "6287b954451580080edd45c2"
}
]

**My Router**

```
router.post('/checkout', auth.verify, (req,res) => {

const data = {
        userId: auth.decode(req.headers.authorization).id,
        orders: req.body.orders
    }

UserController.checkOut(data).then(result => res.send(result));
});
```

**My Controller**

```
module.exports.checkOut = async (data) => {

let isUserUpdated = await User.findById(data.userId).then(user => {

    user.hasPurchased = true

    data.orders.forEach(element => {
        user.orders.push({
            
            cartId: element.cartId,
            
        });
    });

    return user.save().then((user, err) => {
        if(err) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    })


});
    
// DITO AKO NA STUCK---------------------------------
let isCartUpdated = await Cart.findById(data.orders.cartId).then(product => {

    cart.isPaid = true

    return cart.save().then((product, err) => {
        if(err) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    })

})
//-----------------------------------------------------

if(isUserUpdated && isCartUpdated){
    return {message:'Purchase Successful.'}
} else {
    return false;
}
};
```

Comment: Rename the parameter product by cart in the then callback

Comment: Thanks @axelmln appreciaite it. Updated my code but still not defined :(

Answer (score 0):

You try this :

```js
 module.exports.checkOut = async (data) => {

let isUserUpdated = await User.findById(data.userId).then(user => {

    user.hasPurchased = true

    data.orders.forEach(element => {
        user.orders.push({
            
            cartId: element.cartId,
            
        });
    });

    return await user.save().then((user, err) => {
        if(err) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    })


});
    
// DITO AKO NA STUCK---------------------------------
let isCartUpdated = await Cart.findById(data.orders.cartId).then(product => {

    cart.isPaid = true

    return await cart.save().then((product, err) => {
        if(err) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    })

})
//-----------------------------------------------------

if(isUserUpdated && isCartUpdated){
    return {message:'Purchase Successful.'}
} else {
    return false;
}
};
```